# more about bootstrap-theme.css in bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

After downloading bootstrap 3 from http://getbootstrap.com, I found bootstrap-theme.css
i road that for using bootstrap 3 we need just include bootstrap.css or minified version bootstrap.min.css
can you explain more?

Comment: ...what? Did you read the installation instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Bootstrap, you do not need to include the `bootstrap.theme.css` file. This file is intended to bring back some of the styles from the previous major version (2.3.2) of Bootstrap (gradients, box-shadows, etc.)

Here is an example of the styles provided by the theme file.
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/

- Including the theme file = Non-flat Bootstrap v2.3.2 look and feel (kind-of)
- Not including the theme file = new flatter v3.0+ look and feel.